# Как получить /32 ipv6 сеть в ripe не будучи lirом

Tags: proxy, ipv6

Доброго времени суток, нужно получить /32 ipv6 сетку, узнал, что это можно сделать в райпе, но насколько понял есть барьр. Я зарегал аккаунт в райпе, отправил документ подтверждающий личность вот по этой ссылке https://my.ripe.net/#/public/membership-organisation-details, но насколько я понял, это - для получения статуса лира, но я прочитал на хабре, якобы лир стоит 2000 евро и мне соответственно не нужен. Как иначе можно достигнуть цели? ps: сетка нужна под прокси

Comment: Такие вещи наверное только на юр. лиц офомляются, не? И если вы как частное лицо захотите арендовать /32 у тех, кто оформил лира и заплатил эти 2000 -- почему вы думаете, что вам они это сделают дешевле?

Comment: Хорошо, вас понял, то есть получается без лира нельзя. А где тогда лучше приобрести ру  /32 сетку?

Comment: Я не уверен полностью, что нельзя -- возможно, если долго искать найдётся лазейка для физлиц, но лично мне сомнительно. Где взять такую сетку - не знаю, мы брали у провайдеров ipv4 сети на 16 ip-адресов, а потом сразу завели свою AS, BGP и понеслось... Мне кажется, что ваш вопрос лучше задавать не на ru-so, а на более специализированных сайтах, где ближе администраторы хостеров. Тут всё же в основном программисты.